# Are there any repeatable missions with optional objectives, so I can redo the OC/DC Challenge if I reset challenges?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Are there any repeatable missions with optional objectives, so I can redo the OC/DC Challenge if I reset challenges?

I know that if I have the Holodome, there's at least a repeatable side mission there, once I do all the initial missions, so I can redo the "Little on the Side" challenge...

But, can I not reset if I want to get OC/DC to Level 5?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. There is no repeatable missions in Pre-sequel. And the one you talked about above, The Holodome one, isn't really repeating a specific mission, it's playing a mission that has the same objectives.

Comment: Thanks! So, am I right that repeating that missing would at least count to "Little on the Side"?

Comment: @Malady yes I think you could say that it counts. You're welcome.